# TFS copy files to drop location on builds?

Tags: tfsbuild, business-intelligence

I have a tfs 2013 server, and some folks who use BIDS 2008 (SSRS projects/solution) and keep it source controlled via tfs. I know tfs can't build the solution  (it could if we did the one way upgrade, but then the bids 2008 folks can't mess with the solution  anymore).   I can't keep another solution in TFS that is just for building, because what I'd they add another project to the solution in bids, the other solution wouldn't pick up on that.

In the end, what I'd like is to have a build just dump all the *.rdl files from the solution to an output directory.   Not worry about tfs building it I'd I don't have to.

This way they can use bids 2008 for their SSRS projects/solution, and trigger a build that would copy their rdl files to the staging report server.

Suggestions?

Comment: Confirm that question is about building BIDS projects and not about connecting VS 2008 to TFS 2013?

Comment: I thought I made it clear as mud.   Bids 2008 users using tfs 2013 for source control for ssrs rdl reports.  Want tfs to push rdls to a drop location.   Tfs can't build the bids solution unless upgraded, bids folks can't use an upgraded solution.   How to get tfs to copy rdl files to a drop location in a build definition?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563341/creating-a-build-process-template-which-does-nothing-but-copy-all-files-to-anoth